# WSL zsh - Trim working directory if it contains a certain folder

Tags: terminal, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pwd

I'm using WSL to run ohmyzsh on my win 10 machine. I have a repository folder in which I keep my git repositories, and it is my most common working directory. I want to be able to conditionally hide the prompt working directory that comes before this folder.

Currently it looks like this: [image: PWD with long path due to WSL mounting]

I instead want it to resemble the following: `jl@EDEN-WKS-JL > .../repos/react-POC`, replacing anything before `repos` with a `...`, but obviously only doing this if `repos` is in the PWD.

I've tried using the answer provided this question on AskUbuntu ([Trim the terminal command prompt working directory](https://askubuntu.com/q/17723/860844)), but I could not get the answer to work, so that I could modify it for my needs. As I want it to be conditional based on a particular folder, and I'm not in bash, I don't think I can use the `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` bash variable.

How can I conditionally trim the PWD in zsh, based on the contents of the PWD?

## Update

I've tried setting the following in `~/.zshrc`, while it does mostly work, it breaks the styling. (also this is the first time I've used sed, so this could likely be improved)

`PS1=$(echo $PWD | sed 's/\(.*\/repos\)/~\/...\/repos/')`

[image: truncated path, but broken styling]

Comment: Which theme are you using in zsh? Those are prompt text and can be changed with `PS1` environment variable in RC file, like .bahsrc, .zshrc etc. Or change the theme that zsh is using.

Comment: agnoster theme, I'll add my progress to the question

Comment: Try some simple ones, here are the list https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/External-themes